# add an element to a node, if it doesnot exist, based on matching criteria

Tags: xslt-3.0

Using XSLT 3.0,

I have as input the following XML:

```
<?xml ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
        <DATA RECORDS="2">
            <RECORD ID="1">
                <RECNO>1</RECNO>
                <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <ORDER>10355</ORDER>
                <CN>PL</CN>
                <PROPERTY>06</PROPERTY>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="2">
                <RECNO>2</RECNO>
                <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <ORDER>000026672</ORDER>
                <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="3">
                <RECNO>3</RECNO>
                <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
                <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
                <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            </RECORD>
        </DATA>
    </TABLE>
```

given values used for matching:
(i use \t to define the tab separated nature of my input file)

```
"10355"\t"PL"
"000026672"\t"PL 300 L"
```

i need to insert to all records that do not already have a PROPERTY tag, with the value of 06

Desired result:

```
 <?xml ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
        <DATA RECORDS="2">
            <RECORD ID="1">
                <RECNO>1</RECNO>
                <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <ORDER>10355</ORDER>
                <CN>PL</CN>
                <PROPERTY>06</PROPERTY>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="2">
                <RECNO>2</RECNO>
                <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <ORDER>000026672</ORDER>
                <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
                <PROPERTY>06</PROPERTY>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="3">
                <RECNO>3</RECNO>
                <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
                <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
                <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
                <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
                <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            </RECORD>
        </DATA>
    </TABLE>
```

What i have tried, adds the element property, even if it is already there, so i end up with two elements PROPERTY, in the same node, if it already exists. Could you give me an example implementation, i use SAXON latest release (9.8)

xsl: which adds an element, even when one exists:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl exsl xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'RECORD ID']">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(PRODUCT)">
                    <PRODUCT><xsl:value-of select="98"/></PRODUCT>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="98"/></xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Have been using the solution suggested with my real data, (which differ a lot from the example), and i face the following issue:

How could i also have a report that would let me know, which of the additions while they were to be done, according to the input file, were not inserted?

Comment: Looks rather similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419943/add-an-element-to-a-node-if-it-doesnot-exist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588096/append-data-ton-an-element-based-on-matching-this-exact-element, both questions with similar input data and with answers. Are you doing a course with exercises or where does that format come from?

Comment: i have this similar problem also, have seen the above question and answer, so thought i would use those sample data. What i try to do is add a tag, if it is not already there, in each node, based on matching criteria. So the questions in general could be then: How should i give as input the data, to be matched?   And which xslt i should use, in order to insert a tag with a value to each node, that matches the criteria: the matching criteria are as follows: Do insert a tag, only when TAG A and TAG B equal the values given.

Comment: See the similar questions and answer like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345801/add-data-to-an-element-or-create-one-if-it-doesnot-exist-based-on-record-match where tab separated data is compared to the nodes in the input.

Comment: i have used the above question's solution, and while i have say 100 lines to match against, only 88 tags were added. Is there a way to have a log along the substitution, in order to know exactly what happened?

Comment: Use `xsl:message` to output nodes, variables or debug expressions as needed.

Comment: a full xsl example with the above example data, to understand what you mean please? i think a meaningful message could be: from the to be matched values, these did not match in the end, thus the tag was not added. In a case of thousands of records, something that could quickly give the info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

(a) in your sample output, the PROPERTY element has been deleted from record 3. I can't see anything in your description of requirements that explains why.

(b) in your requirements statement, the sentence "i need to insert to all records that do not already have a PROPERTY tag, with the value of 06" is ambiguous. I would read this as saying that if there is a PROPERTY 'tag' (correctly, element) with a value other than 06 then you should insert another PROPERTY element, but that seems to contradict what you say elsewhere.

(c) your code has a template rule with `match="//*[local-name() = 'RECORD ID']"`. You can delete the "//" at the start of a match pattern, it's redundant. More importantly, no element will ever have a local name equal to "RECORD ID" - element names cannot include spaces. So the template rule will never match anything.

(d) assuming that this template rule was intended to match RECORD elements, you certainly don't want the xsl:copy inside the xsl:otherwise, as this will create a nested copy of the whole RECORD.

(e) you've asked for an XSLT 3.0 solution but there's nothing in your problem that requires XSLT 3.0, and in fact your own stylesheet says version="2.0".

(f) I can't see what role the tab-separated parameter file plays in any of this.

In short, there's an awful lot of clarification needed before anyone can start to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution requires a few changes:

1. The template shoud match `RECORD`, not `RECORD ID` (`ID` is an
   **attribute** which takes no part in any decision).
2. Your general concept is OK:

   - copy the starting tag (`<RECORD>`),
   - apply templated to the inside of the current `RECORD`,
   - check whether `PROPERTY` (not `PRODUCT`) element is absent (in the
     current `RECORD`),
   - if it is (absent), then output `PROPERTY` element with the required value,
   - copy the closing tag (`</RECORD>`).
3. I removed the `otherwise` part (not needed) and changed `choose` to
   a single `if`..
4. As you specified **XSLT 3.0**, even the *identity template* can be
   replaced with (a bit shorter) `on-no-match="shallow-copy"`.
5. I also added `version` to your source XML. Otherwise it is not well-formed.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(PROPERTY)">
          <PROPERTY>06</PROPERTY>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested on http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/